# How to compare entire row of a table with entire row of another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way in SQL Server to compare entire row of one table with another table which has same data types.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[PRODUCT]
  (
     [PID]  [INT] NULL,
     [NAME] [NCHAR](10) NULL,
     [PDID] [INT] NULL
  )
```

`select * from product p, product c where p.{entirerow} = c.{entirerow}`

is there some kind of option here?

Answer (score 18):

Use SQL INTERSECT(all matching rows) and EXCEPT (all different rows), [here for example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM Table2
SELECT * FROM Table1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM Table2
```

You can compare subsets of columns by replacing * with a column list or subsets of rows by using a WHERE clause.

One caveat is that the schema's of the tables need to be the same.

Comment: CAN WE USE THEM IN WHERE CLAUSE IF SO PLEASE GIVE A SAMPLE?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. INTERSECT will give you all the matching rows as per your example.

Comment: I know this is old - but was useful to me today. Simon's answer is correct: Intersect gives distinct list of matching identical rows; except returns rows from first table where identical matches cannot be found in second table. Ideally, if you were searching for differences, you would have to the "except" twice: table 1 except table 2 and table 2 except table 1. I wish i could mark this as solved.